# Counting floors

Tags: vocabulaire, nombres

I understand that in French we refer to floors as "rez-de-chaussée, premier étage" etc., but if you want to tell someone how many floors a building has, does this still hold? I.e. if it only has the ground floor, does it have *aucun étage*, or if the floor highest up is the "deuxième étage," does it have *deux étages*? I feel like that's how I learned it in school but it's been a while so I wanted to double check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right:
[according to the TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tage), étage seems to refer to the space between two floors, so you'd need indeed two floors to make *un étage*.

A house with only the ground floor has "aucun étage", it is "[de plain-pied](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plain-pied)".
A house with three floors, so the *rez-de-chaussée* + *le premier étage* + *le deuxième étage* has *deux étages*. The ground floor is implicit. This same house has *trois niveaux* (levels, floors).

Note that historically, [both versions seem to be correct](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/%C3%A9tage):

> Le premier étage, anciennt. et encore au Canada, le rez-de-chaussée ;
>   auj., l'étage carré situé au-dessus du rez-de-chaussée ou de
>   l'entresol.

*Disclaimer after reading some comments: the following statement is based on a few buildings I saw, which doesn't mean it's a rule, just that it can happen.*
In some buildings and industrial constructions, the actual numbering may vary (probably depending on how it was designed). I have seen the rez-de-chaussée being numbered 1 and the following floors 2,3,4, etc. It's absolutely not the most common situation, though.

Comment: In France, I have never seen a rez-de-chaussée with number 1. It's always 0 if it has a number. If you can walk in from the street to floor number 1, it's because the building is on a hillside and has entrances on both floor 0 (normally the main entrance) and floor 1 (typically a back entrance if it isn't numbered 0).

Comment: @Gilles Well I've worked in at least two different buildings (different companies, no relation) with the rdc numbered 1, and visited some others occasionally, so I can confirm that it does happen. Just "pour l'anecdote", I've even worked in a place where rdc was labeled 1, but because of the hillside the entrance was on the 1st floor ...so you entered on a floor labeled 2!

Comment: I agree with @Gilles. The ground floor is always labeled *0* or *RdC* in France. You might have floor *1*  (or higher) accessible from the ground level but that is because the building is on a sloping ground and the other side does starts at level *0*. Otherwise, the upper side is called *RdC* and the lower level is called *RdJ* (for *rez-de-jardin*).

Comment: @jlliagre as I said, I thought so too until I found a building where it's not the case. I'm not saying it's common, just that it happens.

Comment: I'm still unconviced. Where is the building located? Are you sure it is not on a sloped place?

Answer (score 4):

When talking about a building that has only ground floor, we say [bâtiment, maison, appartement] de *plain-pied*. Ground floor in France refers to floor zero.
When we say that a building has *n* floors, it's the number of floors without ground floor (so it would be *n+1* in other languages).

Answer (score 4):

En plus d'étages, on peut parler de niveaux: un immeuble de cinq étages a six niveaux.

Answer (score -1):

the way for anglophone to solidify a 'floor, or, 'space of each floor' as étage is think of 'a stage.' Each level is a stage that life is performed.